# Redirecting old pages to homepage/index

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo

I have taken over an old domain and put a new site on it, it use to be a membership site so I have thousands of old URLs that now go to a 404 page.

Should I redirect these to the homepage to keep the link juice, it is a relative subject, so the links are useful.

If so how would I do it? This is a wordpress site.

/user/*
/image/*/*

What is the best way to deal with these 404's?

Answer (score 0):

I would redirect them to your homepage. Google (and all other crawlers) will notice the change, so you can provide a better and continuous user experience for your users.

Answer (score 0):

There is a brilliant plugin called Redirection (https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) that will allow you to configure redirects in WP, including logs of 404's that visitors to your site experience to help you know where redirects might be necessary.

A word of caution: there are some major implications to putting redirects in place including effects on your site's SEO. I recommend you read up on the different kinds of redirects and what they do.

Reading on the topic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections